# "bash: __gitdir: command not found" error in terminal

Tags: git, bash, terminal

Whenever I'm working in the command window, I get the error: "bash: __gitdir: command not found" right above the working line (in other words, right after any command, before it prompts for a new one).

Any ideas as to what is going on to bring this up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have something calling that command in your `.bashrc` file.

Try searching for __gitdir in it:

```
$ grep __gitdir ~/.bashrc
```

Or maybe post its content, and it will probably be easier to help.

Comment: yep, we were calling it in the .bashrc file. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`__gitdir` is a function supplied by the `git-completion.bash` script that lets bash do auto-complete when you type `git` commands. Are you using `__gitdir` in your `.bashrc` or other profile/login script without sourcing `git-completion.bash`?

Answer (score 0):

The fancy git prompt may be enabled via the function `__git_ps1`, which can be embedded in `PS1` and called every time your prompt is printed. It's defined when sourcing a specific, but potentially different file than the one that defines `__gitdir`. The `__git_ps1` (which calls `__gitdir`) could be in perhaps `/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt` or `/usr/share/git-core/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh` or `/etc/bash_completion.d/git` (etc)...

But if `__git_ps1` ends up getting defined, but `__gitdir` does not, then you would get this error (every time your prompt is printed).  For example, if `__gitdir` is defined in `/etc/*`, but `__git_ps1` is found in `/usr/share/*`, then in a chroot env you may end up with `__git_ps1` defined but `__gitdir` not defined.

To "quiet" the error message, either remove the fancy git prompt, or just define it:  `__gitdir() { :; }`

Answer (score 0):

This will not exactly address the original question context, but might be useful for newer Ubuntu users migrating from older versions...

I recently upgraded an old Ubuntu 12.04 machine to newer version of Ubuntu and I started seeing errors about `__git_dir` missing due to my `PS1` settings like explained by the other answers. To understand why this shell function was not any more defined I figured my `.bashrc` was not up-to-date with the newer Ubuntu conventions.

My old `.bashrc` that was based on the one originally provided by old Ubuntu system had something similar to this:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
  . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

while `.bashrc` files created by newer Ubuntu systems first try to use `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`:

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

When I replaced the old bash completion sourcing with the newer one, I got `__git_dir` defined and was happy ever after.