# Test if current repo is under Git in Bash

Tags: git, bash

Basically, in my .bash_profile, I want to have something to the extent of:

```
[[ __gitdir ]] && echo 'foo'
```

where if __gitdir is true and/or returns anything, I will echo foo. I have tried a few things, and any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel &>/dev/null
```

although the wording of your question confuses me a bit.  That will succeed (return 0) when run anywhere in a Git repo and fail (return non-zero) otherwise, but produces no output, and so is good for chaining with `&&` or using with `if`.

Note that this does not go inside a `[[ ... ]]` test, e.g.

```
  git rev-parse --show-toplevel &>/dev/null && echo "$PWD is in a Git repo." || echo "$PWD is not in a Git repo."
```

will announce whether the current working directory is in a Git repo or not.

Comment: what is the advantage of this over doing ( __gitdir &>/dev/null  && echo "foo")? both seem to work. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Oh, I didn't even realize that `__gitdir` was a literal function! I thought it was just a name you made up, and that you were looking for an implementation of such a function. But, I still think the `git rev-parse` approach is better, because it's more robust: it does not depend on Git completion being installed. Indeed, [Git completion is not installed for everyone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314674/bash-gitdir-command-not-found-error-in-terminal).

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
git rev-parse --quiet --git-dir
```

It's actually what Git uses itself in git-sh.setup.sh for their shell scripts.

Comment: Note that the `--quiet` does not actually make the command quiet!?!?

Comment: It should. IIRC you are right, but that's a bug, it should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I just do this. Not fullproof, but it has worked for me for some time

```
if [ -d .git ]
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/9ef3af2/.bashrc#L27)

Comment: was doing this (and then doing it with an or ../.git too) but i imagine that that is inefficient after a few levels (and I plan on running this every time I change directory)

Comment: This is *not* the same as `__gitdir`. The `__gitdir` command seems to be equivalent to `git rev-parse --top-level`. I.e., `__gitdir` succeeds when PWD is anywhere under a Git repo, whereas `[ -d .git]` will only work at the top-level of a Git repo.

Comment: right, and I wanted it for all (or at least, say, 5) levels into a directory

Answer (score 0):

The following command silences its output so you can check the exit status cleanly:

```
git rev-parse --git-dir &> /dev/null
```

Usage with if/else:

```
if git rev-parse --git-dir &> /dev/null; then
    echo "in git dir"
else
    echo "not a git dir"
fi
```